# how to lock GMSCameraPosition movement in GMSMapView

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to lock the camera in Google Maps for iOS without success so far.

the goal is to point the camera to one location and prevent from the user the ability to move the camera himself. after a while i would like to give the user the camera control back

Thanks

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate zoom:mapView_.camera.zoom];    
[mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:camera];
//here i would like to lock the camera
//do some stuff
//give the user the control back
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `setAllGesturesEnabled` method on [`GMSUISettings`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings). For example:

```
[mapView_.settings setAllGesturesEnabled: NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 
i actually used the "camera will move" delegate to keep the camera in the same place. 
because i wanted the use to be able to interact with the map but not moving the camera.

Comment: @idanOS would you like to share how you implemented this? I followed your idea and it works to an extent, but I do face issues with smoothly swiping the menu over the map, especially canceling an edge swipe that has already started.